# How to force Eclipse to start with empty project explorer?

Tags: eclipse, stm32, workbench

I want to somehow make Eclipse (System Workbench for STM32 to be exact) start with an empty Project Explorer window so I don't see previous projects and can reuse their names for the new projects.

I have not found any setting in Eclipse itself. So I tried deleting all of the content of `workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects` directory
(except *RemoteSystemsTempFiles*) using batch file but the project names remained in Project Explorer and I had to remove them manually anyway. I want to do it automatically. 
Is it possible at all?

Comment: touching the metadata is never a good idea. Explain what you mean by "reuse their names. You can delete the old project and create or import \a new one

Comment: If you want to keep the old projects use a new workspace. If you don't want to keep the old projects delete them properly in Eclipse.

Comment: So basically you want Eclipse to "forget" which projects you've had open last time when you were closing it. As far as I'm aware, there's no such functionality in Eclipse. You can of course keep a copy of your workspace somewhere which doesn't have any projects imported and simply replace your current workspace with the empty/template one (e.g. with a batch that does overwrite and starts Eclipse). Imported projects are kept in workspace so that will work, however so are your settings. Every time you do such overwrite, it'll also overwrite any changes you've made to the Eclipse settings.

Comment: Exactly - I want Eclipse to forget previous session so that the user always have to open his current project manually and don't see other projects in Project Explorer list. And I want to make it work automatically withut any need for user interaction - directly from Eclipse or externally (batch file for example, or any other method). Overwriting setting may also be good. So - you suggest to overwrite the whole C:\Users\"user"\workspace folder? Whould it be enough?

Comment: That will be enough but as I said, that overwrites ALL your changes from the previous session including settings, layout etc.